# Composer Error Installing laravel/installer in Windows 10

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-8

I am using Windows 10 and composer. I'm getting an error when I attempt to install the laravel installer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the full output when I attempt to install:

```
$ composer global require laravel/installer
Changed current directory to C:/Users/rudy/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Using version ^4.1 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been created
Running composer update laravel/installer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 12 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking laravel/installer (v4.1.0)
  - Locking psr/container (1.0.0)
  - Locking symfony/console (v5.1.8)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.20.0)
  - Locking symfony/process (v5.1.8)
  - Locking symfony/service-contracts (v2.2.0)
  - Locking symfony/string (v5.1.8)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 12 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.20.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/process (v5.1.8): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.20.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.20.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.20.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.20.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/string (v5.1.8): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.2.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.20.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/console (v5.1.8): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/installer (v4.1.0): Extracting archive
    Skipped installation of bin bin/laravel for package laravel/installer: name conflicts with an existing file
6 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
Generating autoload files

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "C:\Users\rudy\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor/symfony/polyfill-php73/Resources/s
  tubs" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder


require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Composer 4 times before making this post.  After unsuccessfully trying the solutions above, I tried reinstalling composer again and then ran the laravel/installer - and it worked fine. Thanks to everyone who took the time to reply.

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when the files are corrupted in your local environment. Try removing cache and re-installing the packages

```
$ composer clearcache
$ composer global require laravel/installer
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick reply, but that did not work.  Same error after clearing cache.

Answer (score 3):

You Have Problem with **symfony/polyfill**
*Delete Manually Vendor and composer.lock*

**Or**
Cleaning composer cache worked for me:

```
composer clearcache
```

**Then**
Install your package

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  Unfortunately, none of these work for me.  So I tried installing the Composer.exe for the umpteenth time and then ran the laravel/installer and it worked fine.

Comment: You're welcome, because composer.exe will stuck if have a plugin error. So after u you ran anything, get used to it for `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear` then `composer clearcache`

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading and installing the composer.exe

Comment: This might be better suited as a comment and not as an answer to the problem.

Comment: 50 reputation is needed to make a comment

Answer (score 0):

Having the cache cleared did work for me as well.
here are what I do:

1. composer clearcache
2. composer global require laravel/installer
   and the installation went successfully

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was 7zip.
Composer was using 7z.exe from Lua (which I had previously installed).
When I installed 7z from the official site and updated the PATH variable, this error was solved.
I can't provide an explanation though, I am not sure what happened...